# Drawing in canvas becomes slower and slower when it draws more stuff during loop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to incrementally draw 3 lines which are 120 degrees from each other from a point using html5 canvas. The vertex of each lines will become another 3 new center point and spawns another 3 lines at each center and it repeats this..

My problem is, the incremental speed becomes slower and slower (or the drawing becomes slower) as more items are drawn. (maybe something happens in my code but I am not quite familiar how canvas exactly works...). You can copy the code and run it in your local browser to see what I means.

Please see my code (it is very easy to understand) and tell me what causes this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" ></canvas>

<script>

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame ||  window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
    })();

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width= window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height= window.innerHeight;

    // some staring test values
    var centerPt={x:canvas.width/2,y:canvas.height/2};
    var radius=100;
    var angle=0;

    // calculate the 3 endpoints at 120 degree separations
    var endPt000=anglePoint(centerPt,90);
    var endPt120=anglePoint(centerPt,210);
    var endPt240=anglePoint(centerPt,330);

    var length = 0;
    var maxLength = 100;
    var centreSet = new Array();
        centreSet = getCentres();
    var counter = 0;
    var end = centreSet.length;
    init();

    function init() {
        start(centreSet[0].x, centreSet[0].y);
    }

    function start(myX, myY) {
        centerPt.x = myX;
        centerPt.y = myY;
        animate(centerPt, length);
    }

  function animate(centerPt,length) {
    // update
    // clear
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // draw stuff
    draw(centerPt,length);
    length = length + 1;
    // request new frame
    if(length < maxLength){
        requestAnimFrame(function() {
          animate(centerPt,length);
        });
    }
    else{
        if(counter < end){
            counter = counter + 1;
            centerPt.x = centreSet[counter].x;
            centerPt.y = centreSet[counter].y;
            endPt000=anglePoint(centerPt,90);
            endPt120=anglePoint(centerPt,210);
            endPt240=anglePoint(centerPt,330);
            length = 0;
            setTimeout(function(){animate(centerPt, length);},600);
        }
    }
  }

// draw a red center dot
// draw 3 blue endpoint dots
// draw 3 lines from center going slider% of the way to the endpoints 
function draw(centerPt,sliderValue){

    var pct=sliderValue;
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    line(centerPt,pointAtPercent(centerPt,endPt000,pct),"green");
    line(centerPt,pointAtPercent(centerPt,endPt120,pct),"green");
    line(centerPt,pointAtPercent(centerPt,endPt240,pct),"green");

}

// calc XY at the specified angle off the centerpoint 
function anglePoint(centerPt,degrees){
    var x=centerPt.x-radius*Math.cos( degrees*Math.PI/180 );
    var y=centerPt.y-radius*Math.sin( degrees*Math.PI/180 );
    return({x:x,y:y});
}

// just draw a line from point1 to point2
function line(pt1,pt2,color){
   // ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(pt1.x,pt1.y);
    ctx.lineTo(pt2.x,pt2.y);
    ctx.strokeStyle=color;
    ctx.lineWidth=2;
    ctx.stroke();
}

// calc XY which is a specified percent distance from pt1 to pt2
function pointAtPercent(pt1,pt2,sliderValue) {
    // calculate XY at slider% towards pt2
    var x = pt1.x + (pt2.x-pt1.x) * sliderValue/100;
    var y = pt1.y + (pt2.y-pt1.y) * sliderValue/100;
    return({x:x,y:y});
}

//the following are used to get all the center points...
function getCentres() {
    var x = window.innerWidth/2;
    var y = window.innerHeight/2;
    centreSet[0] = centerPt;
    var ref = 0;
    var end = 0;
    var b = true;
    var tempCenter = centerPt;
    for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        tempCenter = centreSet[ref];
        end = end + 1;
        centreSet[end] = anglePoint(tempCenter,90);
        end = end + 1;
        centreSet[end] = anglePoint(tempCenter,210);
        end = end + 1;
        centreSet[end] = anglePoint(tempCenter,330);

        ref = ref+1;

    }
    return centreSet;
}
   </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are appending and appending the path. This means that each time you call `stroke()` the new line together with all the old lines are stroked. You won't see this clearly as the old lines are drawn on top in the same location. And as more and more lines are added the more time it takes to stroke them..

To prevent this you need to break the path. Do this with `beginPath()`.

If you activate your out-commented line it should work fine:

```
function line(pt1,pt2,color){
    ctx.beginPath(); //<-- activate this
    ctx.moveTo(pt1.x,pt1.y);
    ctx.lineTo(pt2.x,pt2.y);
    ctx.strokeStyle=color;
    ctx.lineWidth=2;
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: but by adding beginPath() that means u r starting a new path, so at each time when u request a new frame, the content u previously drew are all gone...

Comment: Hi Ken maybe you can answer my question. The only reason I removed the beginPath() is because I want to keep what I already drawn in the canvas. I tried context.save() and restore() but none of them works since the save() only saves trokeStyle, fillStyle, globalAlpha, lineWidth, lineCap... but not the path! (reference: http://html5.litten.com/understanding-save-and-restore-for-the-canvas-context/)

Comment: If you want to keep what you already drew, just comment out the line with `ctx.clearRect` in your `draw()` function.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I got where I was confusing at.

Comment: No problem @HughH :) Feel free to post more questions if there is anything. You can also mark answers you receive as accepted by ticking the box under the vote counter. Cheers! :-)